# How to add Google AutoComplete/AutoSuggest feature in rails using Google Ajax API?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have successfully integrated google ajax search with rails application .
Does Google Ajax Search Api provides api for autocomplete/autosuggest feature in rails application ? . Is there a way to integrate google search autocomplete feature in Rails ?

Any body worked on the same please share your experience . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know if this answers your question, but there's plugin that does that for rails  at http://github.com/mdh/g_suggest. 
Hope it helps..